# The inlet on my water heater is leaking.

Tags: water-heater

The pipe is corroded.If I clean it up is there a way to wrap this or something to apply to stop the leak? i don't think removing is an option.

Comment: On the contrary - removal and replacement is the only option that won't lead to a big leak in short order. If it's out of your skill set, calling a plumber now will be a lot cheaper than after it's blown out and sprayed the area with water.

Comment: Can you post a photo with the area of the leak marked?

Answer (score -1):

If it uses flexible connections, all you need is two adjustable wrenches and [a set of supply lines](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Plumbing-Plumbing-Parts-Repair-Shut-off-Valves-Supply-Lines-Supply-Lines/Water-Heater-Connector/N-5yc1vZbqjnZ1z138i0). Do them both, even if the other one doesn't leak yet. Braided steel is a lot easier to work with than the corrugated copper type.

You could try [plumber's epoxy putty](https://www.google.com/search?q=plumbers%20epoxy%20putty&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), but you'd only be delaying an inevitable catastrophic leak.

If it's hard piped and you do call out a plumber, specify that you want it re-done with flex (so that you can DiY next time).

Some thought should be given to the inspection and replacement of your dielectric fittings (or the rectification to the complete lack thereof).